# Is it possible to have a recursive function call another function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am trying to complete my final project for a C++ course. I will try to explain this because it is a bit confusing. I am creating an online shopping cart. I am a beginner so I want to know if it is possible for a recursive function to call an outside function? I have a function with a for loop that calculates the sum of a vector but our instructions are to create a recursive function instead. In addition, the for loop calls another function. Is this possible to do in a recursive function? We have to put these into separate files. 2 header files named ShoppingCart and ItemToPurchase. 2 cpp files name ShoppingCart and ItemToPurchase and 1 main cpp file.

Function declaration of PrintTotal() and GetCostofCart() in a ShoppingCart.h file within a class:

```
class ShoppingCart {
public:
    ShoppingCart();

    double GetCostofCart();

    void PrintTotal();

private:
    vector< ItemToPurchase > cartItems;
};
```

Function definition in ShoppingCart.cpp to print total:

```
void ShoppingCart::PrintTotal() {

    if (cartItems.size() == 0) {
        cout << "Shopping cart is empty" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++) {
        cartItems.at(i).PrintItemCost();
        cout << " " << endl;  
    }
    cout << "Total: $" << GetCostofCart() << endl;
}
```

Function definition in ShoppingCart.cpp for GetCostofCart():

```
double ShoppingCart::GetCostofCart() {

    int costofCart = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++) {
        costofCart += cartItems.at(i).GetPrice() * cartItems.at(i).GetQuantity();
    }
    return costofCart;
}
```

Function declaration in ItemtoPruchase.h file within a class:

```
class ItemToPurchase {
public:
    ItemToPurchase();

    void PrintItemCost();

private:
    double itemPrice;
    int itemQuantity;
};
```

Function definition in ItemToPurshcase.cpp file to print the item cost:

```
void ItemToPurchase::PrintItemCost() {
    cout << itemName << " " << itemQuantity;
    cout << " @ $" << itemPrice;
    cout << " = $" << itemPrice * itemQuantity << endl;
}
```

Function in main.cpp to call PrintTotal:

```
 void OutputCart(ShoppingCart& cart) {

    cout << endl;
    cout << "OUTPUT SHOPPING CART" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cart.PrintTotal();
}
```

Calling a function in if/else if statement based on a users input:

```
        else if (userChoice == 'o') {
            cout << customerName << "'s Shopping Cart" << endl;
            cout << "Today's Date: " << currentDate << endl;
            OutputCart(cart);
        }
```

I have tried a number of different ways to do this but I am not successful. I have tried searching the internet for solutions but could not find a good example to work from. I am wondering if this is even possible and if so how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, yes; any function can call any function, including itself.  So probably there is something else wrong, but your question doesn't really make clear what it is.

Comment: Can you turn this into a [mcve]: a small but compilable program demonstrating the problem (if possible, in just one file), and an explanation of what goes wrong (exact error message or description of incorrect behavior).

Comment: Yes, it is possible; recursive functions have no special restrictions on what other functions they can call.  I don’t see any recursive functions in your posted code, though.

Comment: What happens when you walk through it in your debugger?

Comment: Recursion is highly inappropriate for something like computing shopping cart totals.  It might be a good idea to show the exact wording of your assignment, just in case you're interpreting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, there are no restrictions, as mentioned in the comments.
However, also as mentioned in the comments, I see no recursive function in your code. I guess you wanted to create a recursive function from `GetCostOfCart`. One approach to achieve this would be something like the following:

```cpp
double ShoppingCart::GetCostofCart(int current_item) {
    // termination
    if (current_item == cartItems.size()){
        return 0;
    }
    // recursion
    else {
        return cartItems.at(current_item).GetQuantity() * cartItems.at(current_item).GetPrice() + GetCostofCart(current_item + 1);
    }
}
```

Each function call is responsible for adding the price of one entry in the car list to the total price. However, please note that the function signature was changed (it now takes an int argument). Just call this function with the argument 0, and it will call itself and calculate the total price.

Maybe there are some `this` missing, I would have to double-check. However, in any way, recursive function calls are technically no different to regular function calls.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!